# MPC and MPS relationship

Tags: macroeconomics, consumption

I have a question from an old assignment that I cant wrap my head around.

```
Other things remaining the same, if households suddenly decide to save more at each level of income, then the consumption function will:

a) become steeper because the marginal propensity to consume (MPC) falls.
b) become less steep because the marginal propensity to save (MPS) rises.
c) make a parallel shift downward as autonomous consumption expenditure falls.
d) remain unchanged but the savings function will shift downward.
```

I don't understand why it can't be option B. 
   Since

```
MPS+MPC = 1
```

and

```
C = C₀ + (MPC)Y (Consumption function = Auto. Consumption + MPC(Income))
```

Given this, if MPS increases - it should mean that MPC decreases and so the slope of the consumption function decreases. Hence, option B. The answer however is C and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in stating that if MPS increases, then MPC decreases.  But the question doesn't actually say that MPS increases. What it says is that saving increases at *each* level of income. That's consistent with a scenario such as the following in which MPS does not change while autonomous consumption falls from $10$ to $5$:

$\qquad$**Before**: $S = -10 + 0.2Y$ and $C = 10 + 0.8Y$

$\qquad$**After**: $S = - 5 + 0.2Y$ and $C = 5 + 0.8Y$

In this scenario, consumption falls by $5$ at each level of income - a parallel shift of the consumption function as per option C.

Actually, the question is not as precisely worded as it could have been.  If C is given as the correct answer, the implication is that households decide to save *the same amount* more at each level of income.  That could have been made explicit.

Comment: @Zafir Khalid I've edited my answer to highlight the role of autonomous consumption.  I believe it's an improvement - but you are free to withdraw your acceptance if you disagree.